# Why the Spring Boot controller can't handle other requests if Thread.sleep is used?

Tags: java, spring-boot

When we use the `Thread.sleep(...)` method in the Spring Boot controller, we cannot accept requests concurrently. All requests can only be processed one by one. Why not every request is processed in parallel？

For example, there is a `Thread.sleep(...)` in the *sleep* method. In order to simulate the parallel access to the *sleep* method, I used the Chrome browser to open multiple tabs to visit `http://localhost:8080/async`. Observe that multiple tabs are executed in series. Why is it not executed in parallel here?

```java
@RestController
public class AsyncController {

    @RequestMapping("async")
    public String sleep() throws InterruptedException {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("[before]name is " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " time is " + startTime);
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("[after]name is " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " time is " + endTime + " cos " + (endTime-startTime));
        return Thread.currentThread().getName();
    }

}
```

Console printing

```
[before]name is http-nio-8080-exec-2 time is 1602751326997
[after]name is http-nio-8080-exec-2 time is 1602751337000 cos 10003
[before]name is http-nio-8080-exec-3 time is 1602751337004
[after]name is http-nio-8080-exec-3 time is 1602751347008 cos 10004
```

Comment: How are you sending the requests?

Comment: Yup. Using something like Tomcat?

Comment: @Tom Access the http path corresponding to the controller

Comment: @PrashantPandey Yes, using tomcat

Comment: That you need to use the path is obvious, but what tool do you use to do that? It is possible that the problem is not Spring but your tool that waits until one requests completes before sending another one.

Comment: Can you log the threadId before it sleeps? Also, how many threads have you configured in your Tomcat's pool?

Comment: Why it can print 2 time of `[before]` ?

Comment: @DoNhuVy because I opened the two tabs of chrome and visited the path once

Comment: Why the vaue of time is too much: `03/03/52759 @ 1:56pm (UTC)`?

Comment: @DoNhuVy It's millisecond

Comment: @Tom after using postman, it can be accessed in parallel. It may be a feature of chrome